# Conditional Probability... (?)

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand a proof from a video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBFpqjNZXV0&list=PLFDbGp5YzjqXQ4oE4w9GVWdiokWB9gEpm&index=52

The setting is as follows: We have a prob. space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and a discrete random variable 
$X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N}_0$ which is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$, i.e.
  $$P[X=k] = \lambda^k e^{-\lambda}/k!, ~~ k \in \mathbb{N}_0$$
but here comes the catch: we regard $\lambda$ as a varying parameter which itself is drawn from a random variable $\Lambda : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and assume that this is $\gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ distributed, i.e. it has a density
  $$f(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}$$
i.e. actually we are talking about a map $\tilde{X} : \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
that is *not* jointly measurable (i.e. not a random variable!) but for every fixed
$\lambda$, $\tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)$ is a Poisson$(\lambda)$-distributed random variable.
We are also given an observation $x = X(\omega)$ and try to figure out something about the $\lambda$ from $x$.

Now what this guy is writing down confuses me:
 $$ P(\lambda|x) = \frac{P(x|\lambda)P(\lambda)}{P(x)} \propto P(x|\lambda)P(\lambda) = \lambda^k e^{-\lambda}/k! \cdot f(\lambda)$$

I assume that the symbols have the following meaning (correct me, if Im wrong):
$$P(\lambda|x) = P(\Lambda=\lambda|\tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)=x)$$
$$P(x|\lambda) = P(\tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)=x|\Lambda=\lambda)$$

I am aware of the fact that $P(\tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)=x|\Lambda=\lambda)$ is not the original conditional probability but the factorization of the conditional expected value $E[1_{\tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)=x}|\Lambda]$.

Here are my questions:

(1) I cannot make sense of $P(\lambda|x)$. If it means $P(\Lambda=\lambda|\tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)=x)$ then this value should be zero, because $\Lambda$ is real valued!

(2) What version of Bayes Theorem is he using? If the term $P(\text{some Event}|Y=y)$ is senseful and non zero but $P(Y=y|\text{some Event})$ is zero, how can Bayes make sense?

(3) Why is $P(x|\lambda) = \lambda^k e^{-\lambda}/k!$? We just know that is some strange factorization...

Greetings and thanks for your advice :-)

FW

Comment: what is $P$? Can you please change it to $f$ standing for the pdf wherever relevant. Also please change $f(x)=...$ to $f(\lambda)=...$. I agree that things are confusing!

Comment: erm... but both things you mentioned are vital for my question... my questions are: (1) what does P mean? [i.e. does P(...) mean this and that?] (2) [at least partially]: Why are we allowed to insert $\lambda$ into the density? So its important to keep them separated... dont you think?

Comment: I think (3) is answered as follows: in http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/statistik/lehre/SS13/WT/Skript/WT-Buch_8.pdf Satz 8.16 they show that E(h(X,Y)|Y=y) = E(h(X,y)). Fix $\lambda$ and put $X_\lambda = \tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)$. In my case I want to compute $E[1_{X_\lambda \in \{x\}}|\Lambda=\lambda]$ and $1_{X_\lambda \in \{x\}} = 1_{\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}} \circ (X_\lambda, \Lambda)$, i.e. $h(x,y) = 1_{\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}}(x,y)$ and $E(h(X_\lambda, \lambda)) = E(1_{\{x\}}(X(\omega))) = P[X=x]$